# Limit size of UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, uialertview

I have long text in my UIAlertView, I opted to put legalese inside of them. Although the UIAlertViews do have text scrolling, the UIAlertView also decided to stretch to the boundaries of the screen on the top and bottom, without modifying the width. This is not a very aesthetic outcome, I would like UIAlert to stay within a particular size and just have scrollable text.

How would I force the UIAlert to stay a particular size.

Comment: You don't have much control of alert views.  You'll need to build a custom view / layout if want that sort of control.  Or you could paginate it to a size that looks okay to you, and then show multiple alerts.  But that seems like it would be annoying.

Comment: @i_am_jorf unfortunate to become aware of this

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated after iOS8 so I would recommend you to use `UIAlertController`. If you check the documentation in `UIAlertController` you can use scrollable `UITextView` inside `UIAlertController` and that should be solve your problem.